# Lucene.Net when to reindex my datatbase

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, indexing, lucene.net

I am implementing Lucene.Net in my ECommerce application (Asp.Net Mvc3, Sql server 2008), It has got huge database. So Indexing products is getting pretty heavy operation. Though indexing it single time is ok for me.

Now when I update, create, delete any product indexing for particular product should be updated accordingly.

Also I have implemented bulk update for products through Excel sheet. So more number of products are being inserted, updated or deleted through this operation. What approach should I choose to reindex my products?.

As most of the products goes unchanged it might not be good idea to reindex all products and increase load on server.

My code for indexing products is

```
               foreach (var p in products)
                    {
                        //Create the Document object
                        // object temp = p;
                        Document doc = new Document();
                        var properties = p.GetType().GetProperties();
                        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in properties)
                        {
                            //Populate the document with the column name and value from our query
                            var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(p, null);
                            doc.Add(new Field(propertyInfo.Name, value == null ? "" : value.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
                        }

                        // Write the Document to the catalog
                        indexWriter.AddDocument(doc);
                    }
```

Anybody knows workaround for this . Is there any way to index document without using foreach or anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

Use a loop, but only for updated products!

If you have a last modification timestamp in your database, use it to fetch only products updated since last indexing job.
Another way to do it is to add an "indexing status" field to your database. When the product is inserted or modified (via bulk update or another way), this flat is set to 0. When the indexing job run, in the loop you can set this flag to 1.
Then, your indexing job only need to run on all product with flag set to 0.

Dont't forget that in lucene you can't really UPDATE an index: you've to delete the document, and add it again. So in lucene you need field with the product unique identifier, so that you can retrieve the document using this field (via a term query search), and then remove it.

Another tip: `p.GetType().GetProperties()` use reflection and will slown down the process.
If all your products have the same type, create the list of `PropertyInfo` once (outside the loop) so that you only use reflection once. The reuse it in the loop.

Comment: can u depict with some code, how could i delete document of particular product and index it again i.e append it